# Named format string parameters with format specifiers

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, you can substitute arguments into a C-style format string using the [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25) method, like so:

```
'%.3d can be expressed in binary as %b' % [30, 30]
#=> "030 can be expressed in binary as 11110"
```

[`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) and [`Kernel#format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format) behave similarly:

```
sprintf('%.3d can be expressed in binary as %b', 30, 30)
#=> "030 can be expressed in binary as 11110"

format('%.3d can be expressed in binary as %b', 30, 30)
#=> "030 can be expressed in binary as 11110"
```

Ruby also provides the ability to use named parameters within this format string:

```
'Hello, %{first_name} %{last_name}!' % {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}
#=> "Hello, John Doe!"
```

But is there a way to use these features together? E.g.:

```
'%{num}.3d can be expressed in binary as %{num}b' % {num: 30}
# I want: "030 can be expressed in binary as 11110"
# Actual: "30.3d can be expressed in binary as 30b"
```

In other words, is there a way to use flags, width specifiers, precision specifiers, and types in format strings with named parameters? What's the form of `%[flags][width][.precision]type` if I want to give the format sequence a name?

Comment: In the doc [`#format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format), It is mentioned *Ruby supports a reference by name. `%<name>s` style uses format style, but `%{name}` style doesn’t.*  --- This you might missed while reading the doc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
'%<num>.3d can be expressed in binary as %<num>b' % {num: 30}
# => "030 can be expressed in binary as 11110"
```